# How to get real time data from ardunio board using NodeJS and send to my remote server without the wifi module?

Tags: arduino-uno

As the question, How to get real time data from ardunio board using NodeJS and send to my remote server without the wifi module.how to do this without any hardware.

Comment: It's impossible. You need at least some hardware to run Node.js. Your Uno cannot do that.

Comment: @EdgarBonet yes if you are connected to some hardware(computer), you can easily send the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty easy to send data with the help of NodeJS. Here i attach the code.

```
var request = require('request');
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", {
  baudrate: 9600,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});


serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

serialPort.on('data', sendSerialData);

function sendSerialData(data) {
 request({
  uri: "http://127.0.0.1/write_data.php?value="+data,
 method: "GET",
  timeout: 10000,
   followRedirect: true,
   maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) {
   console.log(body);
});


}
```

Comment: if your are connected to your system only you can do this , without any hardware it is not applicable